# Not returning correct result in React component with if elseif statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

I'm using a dropdown menu to choose different levels for a memory game. I'm using an if/elseif statement because there are three variables involved. It console logs the correct results from the Gameboard component but I cannot get it to load the correct level name in the Title component and I don't know why. I presume I need the state object for it to work correctly.

I've tried generating text with CSS, transforming the object into an array (on the second menu choice, this turns each letter of the Title into an array element and then blows up the app), and even tried passing the level title into the title component, but nothing has worked. I'm still figuring out the intricacies of working with components. Thank you!

This is the if/elseif

```
let gameLevel = <div>Level One</div>;
let cards = 18;
let colWidth = 2;

const level = (this.props.type);
        console.log(level);
        if (level === 'first') {
            gameLevel = <div>Level One</div>;
            cards = 18;
            colWidth = 2;
        } else if (level === 'second') {
            gameLevel = <div>Level Two</div>;
            cards = 12;
            colWidth = 3;
        } else if (level === 'third') {
            gameLevel = <div>Level Three</div>;
            cards = 8;
            colWidth = 3;
        } else if (level === 'fourth') {
            gameLevel = <div>Level Four</div>;
            cards = 18;
            colWidth = 2;
        } else if (level === 'fifth') {
            gameLevel = <div>Level Five</div>;
            cards = 12;
            colWidth = 3;
        } else if (level === 'sixth') {
            gameLevel = <div>Level Six</div>;
            cards = 8;
            colWidth = 3;
        } else {
            console.log(gameLevel, cards, colWidth);
        }return gameLevel;
```

This is the title component (I have also passed props instead of newLevel while trying to fix this)

```
const title = (newLevel) => {
    console.log(newLevel);
    const changeLevel = Object.keys(newLevel);
    console.log(changeLevel);

    return (
        <div className={classes.Title}>
            {changeLevel}
        </div>
    )
};




This is the gameboard component (I left out the cards)

class Gameboard extends Component {
state = {
        levels: {
            first: 'Level One',
            second: 'Level Two',
            third: 'Level Three',
            fourth: 'Level Four',
            fifth: 'Level Five',
            sixth: 'Level Six'
        },

        cardCount: {
            first: 18,
            second: 12,
            third:8,
            fourth: 18,
            fifth: 12,
            sixth: 8
        },

        width: {
            first: 2,
            second: 3,
            third: 3,
            fourth: 2,
            fifth: 3,
            sixth: 3
        }
    };
    changeBoard = (type) => {
        const newLevel = this.state.levels[type];
        const newCount = this.state.cardCount[type];
        const newWidth = this.state.width[type];
        console.log(newLevel);
        console.log(newCount);
        console.log(newWidth);

    return <Title levels={newLevel}/>;

render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Row>
                    <Col className={classes.stats}>
                        <Menu changed={this.changeBoard}/>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        <p className={classes.stats}>Matches<br/>0</p>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        <p className={classes.stats}>Attempts<br/>0</p>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        <p className={classes.stats}>Accuracy<br/>0</p>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        <p className={classes.stats}>Wins<br/>0</p>
                    </Col>
                    <Col className={classes.stats}>
                        <button type='button' className='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>Reset</button>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Timer/>
                <Title levels={this.state.levels}/>
//cards here
 </div>
        )
    }
};
export default Gameboard;
```

and in the render...

```
<Title levels={this.state.levels}/>
```

I expect to see "Level One" in the title component when selecting LevelOne in the menu, "Level Two" when selecting Level Two and so on. Instead I get a static "Level One", "Level One1", all the level titles at once, "Level One" displayed 23 times due to the state objects, or the app blows up.

Comment: Can you show the full component?

Comment: I hope I got the correct component.